# Laravel(downloading of data to DB)

Tags: laravel

Good time of day! Who can help in the creation of project at framework "Laravel"? I can't download data in database.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD8xC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use below documents to install the laravel application.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

Comment: I have installed an application and I created models, controllers and other elements...

Comment: @ДмитрийБутов that means your question is not well asked

Comment: Ok, there are any files that can help describe you my problem: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yFsaFng0yIGl9VGMAPzDTPe94xm2FapR?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you understand me?